# Combining two summation into one summation

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I'm struggling with the concept of double finite series in connection with its Decartesian product when I have to prove everything rigorously.

I would like your help to justify this equation below.

Given $f(x,y)$ : $ \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ . We then have:

$\sum\limits_{\substack{x \in \{x_0\}  \\}}$ $\sum\limits_{\substack{y \in \boldsymbol Y \\}} f(x,y)$ = $\sum\limits_{\substack{(x,y) \in \boldsymbol \{x_0\} \times \boldsymbol Y \\}} f(x,y)$

In this question, the intuition is certainly clear but I can't manage to produce a rigorous proof.
**Is this equation is just a matter of notation or is there any "serious proof" or some "formal definition" to combine 2 summations into 1 ?**

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Hint: since $\{x_0\}$ is a singleton, you can rewrite the summation without two summation terms.

Comment: @DonThousand: Yes, i have thought of that. So it is just a matter of notation right ?